# JQuery dataTable mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble trying to mouseover each individual section of my data table. This is how the table is being implemented:

```
$(document).ready(function() {                                  
    var table = $("#rTable").DataTable({
        data: @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.Model.List)),
        columns: [
            {title: "P", data: "P"},
            {title: "P", data: "P"},
            {title: "C", data: "C"},
            {title: "N", data: "N"},
            {title: "A", data: "A"},
            {title: "M", data: "M"},
        ],               
        "order": [[0, "asc"]]
        }
    );
});
```

I want to be able to hover my mouse over anyone of the table outputs and see a detailed box pop-up and then go away after my mouse leaves. I have seen a lot of answers on how to do this with tr and td but I am not using html to create the table. Does anyone have any ideas on how to move forward with this?

Comment: The html is generated server side you mean? There is not much information here to go on. Many unknowns but perhaps delegated events can help you.

Comment: I guess I could have added this: based off this entry- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503806/jquery-datatables-mouseover-issue/9573901#9573901 how would I change the way they used tr and td to use my columns from my DataTable?

Comment: I would need to see what your HTML looks like in the DOM. Update the question with that and I'll show you.

Comment: new question: how do I do I find what my HTML looks like in the DOM? sorry I'm a newbie at this stuff

Comment: No problem. If you are using chrome, and most browsers are like this in general, right click on table and choose inspect element. Then you can copy the HTML directly out of element inspector.

Comment: <div id="List">
    //lots of dataTable HTML I don't need to show
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr role=row>
             <td> Ryan </td>
             <td>014</td>
          </tr>
    //This would be the first row output, other rows look identical in structure

Comment: OK and you want the popup to happen when they hover over a row (tr) or when they hover a cell (td)?

Comment: When you hover over a particular cell (td), so each cell should give a different pop-up depending on its content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found an answer to my question:

```
 $('#rTable tbody td').each(function() {
     var sTitle = table.cell(this).data();
     this.setAttribute('title', sTitle);
 });


 $('#rTable tbody td[title]').tooltip({
     "delay": 0,
     "track": true,
     "fade": 250
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

So as we discussed above if you want to have a popup over each `td` and you don't know exactly how many rows or cells there will be you can use jQuery delegated events.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#rTable').on('mouseover', 'td', function() {
        // show popup for cell
    }).on('mouseout', 'td', function() {
        // hide popup for cell
    });
});
```

This basically tells `rTable` to watch for these events on its descendants and let the element know when it happens. You can then use `this` in the function to access that specific `td` element.

Comment: No problem, let me know how it goes! Good luck!

Comment: your mouseover part is working, but I can't seem to get the data to pop-up. could you show me the code that you left out to show and hide the mouseover pop up?

Comment: Where is the data for the popup coming from? I left that out because I assumed you had a solution for that. Are you using jQueryUI? You could use their tooltip widget. How are you getting the data to display in the popup?

Comment: I was hoping to just get it from my model or from the cell itself, i just want the pop-up to repeat the text in the cell. Since the data for the cell is coming to from the model, how would I use that?

Comment: OK, here is an example. If you are using jQueryUI you can use their tooltip widget. By putting the popup info on a data attribute you can then setup jqueryUI to use that data. https://jsfiddle.net/u3hLpvew/

Comment: No problem. Good luck!!

Comment: One thing I am stuck on, how do I add an attribute to my HTML? Since it is being created server side, I'm not sure how I would use attr with the way I am creating my table

Comment: Unfortunately there is so much of your code I can't see. Without seeing how the server side code is being created I couldn't tell you. Do you have control over the server side code? There are many ways to configure the jQuery tooltips to pull that data from other places but without knowing how you can access that data I couldn't possibly guess.